# On Rails, how to add a new instance with what's "through"ing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So, I'm using rails. And here are three classes

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :ownerships, as: :ownable
  has_many :products, through: :ownerships
end

class Manufacturer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :ownerships, as: :ownable
  has_many :products, through: :ownerships
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :ownerships
end

#  ...
#  ownable_id     :uuid
#  ownable_type   :enum
#  type           :string
#  status         :enum 
class Ownership < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :ownable, polymorphic: true
end
```

So, the situation is, User and Manufacturer can have Product through ownership. And both has ownership as polymorphic association.

And in my controller, I'd like to add a new product right off a user with { type: "PrimaryOwner", status: "Approved" } for the ownership that's going to get created.

The code I'd like to run is simply this...

```
#  product_params is
#  { 
#    name: "My new product ASD-Z23",
#    description: "It's a product at the storage number #123QWERTY",
#    ownership: {
#      type: "PrimaryOwner",
#      status: "Approved"
#    }
#  }    
current_user.products.new(product_params)
```

And what I expect is that code will create a product with the ownership. (Since in the User model, I already told it that it can have product "through" a ownership.)

And of course, this code wasn't working.
Is there any good rails way to do that?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you add your log while you are trying to add whats happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear if you are trying to create a new ownership for the product, or the ownership already exists and you're trying to use that association. If the latter, then you need to use nested routes to specify the ownership (ie ownerships/2/products/new). current_user will just need to be merged with the params.

If you're trying to create a new ownership and the ownership params in product_params are always going to be the same, then you can just run an :after_create callback which calls a method that creates an ownership.

If not an you need the form for both a ownership and a product at the same time, then that'll be a bit trickier. Let me know if that's the case.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear! And yup. I was trying to create a new product off of user, and expecting a 'new' ownership 'auto-generated' by Rails. But the 'relationship' called as 'ownership' wasn't auto-generated, so the product is still not in the list of user.products.